# Check if message contains bad characters?

Tags: php

I have a array of not allowed characters:

```
$array = ('<php', '<?', '?>', '<h', '<b>');
```

And I have a string message.
How do I check that, that string doesn't contains any of these words in the array?

Basically ,I have a ajax chat, and when I type `<b>hello</b>`, it makes the text bold, I don't want to allow HTML there, I have no idea how?

Comment: Have a look at [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Answer (score 2):

You could strip out all html tags using `strip_tags`, but when you output to html, you should always use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) so that any special characters like `>`, `<`, etc. get encoded so they will not have any effect on the generated html.

By the way, a black-list approach is likely to fail, what if people start for example adding `<script>` tags, etc.? Although it does not seem necessary here when you encode correctly for the medium you are outputting to (html, db, etc.), you are generally better of using a white-list approach.

Answer (score 0):

xml Encode anything you are displaying on a webpage...

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need to strip these out. If you use `htmlspecialchars`, then you can encode `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`, so html is passed right along but not rendered by the browser.

As an addition: If you use jQuery, keep in mind that `.text(...)` will escape these things for you. `.html(...)` will not. When outputting html to the browser safely, use `.text(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid Using HTML Tags you can use

```
$value = htmlentities($value);
```

or

```
$value = htmlspecialchars($value);
```

also you can use the two functions

```
$value = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($value));
```